# Is there a way to prove the theorem of Trace as in Evans, in the picture below, using only weak derivatives?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, trace-map

Is there a way to prove the theorem of Trace as in Evans, in the picture below, using only weak derivatives? I mean, without using the divergence theorem?

[image]

Comment: The proof in Evans only uses the fundamental theorem of calculus. If $p=2$ you can use the Fourier transform. If $p \neq 2$, there is probably a high-tech way to use the Fourier transform.